# Values Show up Inaccurately

Tags: javascript, html

Example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/CoolBuys1290/sL12k96h/5/).

When I input 3 and doubles of it, the result in the other field is 2.9999999999999996e+0. I would like it to be 3, but when I input 6, the result is 5.999999999999999e+0

I've tried setting the result to exponential but that didn't fix the problem.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator Portal</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>From:</p>
        <select style="float:left" id="MetricAndImperial1" class="newClass1" oninput="Run2()">
        </select>

         <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000;" id="Input1" type="number" oninput="Run1()" />

        <p>To:</p>

        <select style="float:left" id="MetricAndImperial2" class="newClass1" oninput="Run1()">   
        </select>

        <input style="height:50%;font-size:15pt;width:1000px; border: 1px solid #000;" id="Input2" type="number" oninput="Run2()" />
        <script>
        var units = [
          ['Inches', 0.0254],
          ['Feet', 0.3048],
          ['Furlongs', 1.828800000565]
        ];
        var selectors = document.querySelectorAll('.newClass1');

        for (var i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
         for (var j = 0; j < selectors.length; j++) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = units[i][1];
            option.textContent = units[i][0];
            selectors[j].add(option);
          }
        }
        function Run1() {
          var SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
          document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue.toExponential();

        }

        function Run2() {
          var SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input2").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value;
          document.getElementById("Input1").value = SpecialValue.toExponential();
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect to see 3.0+e0 in the converted field, but instead all I get it 2.9999999999999996e+0

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter in the toExponential function [can be used to specify the number of digits after the decimal point.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential)

By default the function displays as many digits as necessary to specify the number.

So to fix your issue I set the number of digits to show in the second input to be the number of digits entered in your first input and it seems to work.

Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/mftdkboc/

Just to clarify I added `document.getElementById("Input1").value.length` inside your toExponential function.

```
function Run1() {
  var SpecialValue = document.getElementById("Input1").value * document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial1").value / document.getElementById("MetricAndImperial2").value;
  document.getElementById("Input2").value = SpecialValue.toExponential(document.getElementById("Input1").value.length);

}
```